# Override abstract setter of property in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, properties, abstract-methods

What is the simplest / most pythonic way to override only the setter of an abstract property in Python 3? Variant 3 seems to mean the least effort for the derived class implementor. Is it correct? Does it have disadvantages?

```
import abc


class A1(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, x, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value


class B1(A1):
    @property
    def x(self):
        return super().x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        print("B1 setter")
        super(B1, self.__class__).x.fset(self, value)

b1 = B1(x=1)
b1.x = 3
print(b1.x)


class A2(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, x, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._x = x

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def _get_x(self):
        return self._x

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def _set_x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    x = property(_get_x, _set_x)


class B2(A2):

    def _get_x(self):
        return super()._get_x()

    def _set_x(self, value):
        print("B2 setter")
        super()._set_x(value)

    x = property(_get_x, _set_x)

b2 = B2(x=1)
b2.x = 3
print(b2.x)


class A3(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, x, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._x = x

    def _get_x(self):
        return self._x

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def _set_x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    x = property(
        lambda self: self._get_x(),
        lambda self, value: self._set_x(value))


class B3(A3):

    def _set_x(self, value):
        print("B3 setter")
        super()._set_x(value)


b3 = B3(x=1)
b3.x = 3
print(b3.x)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, yes, you listed a lot of ways in there - and although the one that requires more code is your variant 3, the most straighforard, least surprising way to do it is your variant 1 -

It just works, and is perfectly readable, no surprises - and there seems to be no simpler way than calling `fget` explicitly there.